# How to I pass an argument to a Jenkins "readFileFromWorkspace()" script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a freestyle job in jenkins with the following format:

```
freeStyleJob('Myjob') {
    wrappers {
        preBuildCleanup()
    }
    steps {
        shell(readFileFromWorkspace('scripts/myscript.sh'))
    }
}
```

I need to pass a command line argument to my script

i.e.

```
./myscript.sh argument1 argument2
```

How do I do this in a freestyle job?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass command line arguments to your script by modifying the shell step in your Jenkins job.

```
freeStyleJob('Myjob') {
 wrappers {
    preBuildCleanup()
 }
 steps {
    shell "./scripts/myscript.sh argument1 argument2"
 }
}
```

You can also try using Jenkins environment variables to pass arguments to your script.

```
freeStyleJob('Myjob') {
    wrappers {
        preBuildCleanup()
   }
   steps {
      shell """
          export ARG1="argument1"
          export ARG2="argument2"
          ./scripts/myscript.sh \$ARG1 \$ARG2
       """
    }
 }
```

In the above example, I am using triple quotes to create a multi-line shell command. Then exporting two environment variables (**ARG1** and **ARG2**) and then passing them as arguments to the script. The **$** sign prevents Jenkins from interpolating the variables as Jenkins variables.